# sbt not working on amazon ec2 micro instance

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sbt, java

I'm trying to use sbt on an amazon ec2 micro instance but I'm getting this error when I execute sbt command.

```
mkdir prueba
cd prueba
sbt

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps "micro" is just too small for SBT? The message is pretty clear, the initial heap size that the SBT launcher script asked for was unavailable.

Comment: Its trying to allocate way more memory than a micro instance has available. Micro instances only have 613MB of physical memory provisioned to it. Your application is trying to allocate 682MB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally I edited sbopts file in /etc/sbt/ and changed the memory value.

Answer (score 9):

You have to run sbt with a switch limitting the used memory to be less than the available on machine.

Instead of editing files, I run sbt with `sbt -mem 256` for example to get `-Xmx` and `-Xms` to 256MB. Works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I used to run `sbt` on EC2 micro. Previously SBT could be used with 256M heap or possibly even smaller. Try running something like this

`export SBT_OPTS="-Xms128M -Xmx256M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"`

`java $SBT_OPTS -jar`dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally I edited sbopts file in /etc/sbt/ and changed the memory value.